# Get the maximum value of rows from database table

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2005

I need to write a SQL query which will get me those rows from the table which have the max value of files.

The database table is as follows:

```
> ID  status dept  files
> 
> > 1   1   23  1256637314
> > 
> > 1   1   39  1256642968
> > 
> > 2   0   85  1256551419
> > 
> > 2   1   90  1256642968
> > 
> > 2   1   93  1256810937
> > 
> > 3   0   20  1256642968
> > 
> > 5   1   342 1256810937
```

Now from this table i want to get those rows which have the maximum files grouping by ID:

```
> ID  status dept  files
>
> 1    1   39  1256642968
>
> 2    1   93  1256810937
>
> 3    0   20  1256642968
>
> 5    1   342 1256810937
```

Any suggestions??

Thanks.

i tried this but this is not right

```
Select  ID, Status, dept,files
from SLAStat
where files in (Select Max(files) from SLAStat group by ID)




2   1   90  1256642968
1   1   39  1256642968
3   0   20  1256642968
5   1   342 1256810937
2   1   93  1256810937
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace @t1 by your table:

```
With idT as (
    select ID
    from @t1
    group by id
) 
select applyT.* 
from idT p
CROSS APPLY (
    select top 1 * from @t1 where ID=p.ID order by files desc
) as applyT
```

Comment: this was brilliant.... is there a place i can read about how to query like this... it will be a good learning experience for me..

Comment: SQL is a funny language. It takes practice (more than learning the syntax) to write good queries. If I could give you a pointer, I'd tell you to use "With" to separate the different steps in a query, instead of writting long queries. The query optimizer will take care of factoring out the with's for you. CROSS APPLY is an awesome feature too (it's easier to reason about it too).

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.ID, a.Status, a.Dept, a.Files
FROM table a
INNER JOIN (
SELECT ID, MAX(files) AS Files
FROM table
GROUP BY ID) b ON a.ID = b.ID AND a.Files = b.Files
```

Comment: this doesn't guarantee 1 row per ID (if there are two ID's with the same files.. you'll get 2 rows for that ID). Look at my answer to fix this problem.

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near 'InnerJoin'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near 'b'.

Comment: Does the error message literally say 'InnerJoin' or is it 'Inner Join'?  And the difference is that I'm including the ID in the subquery.

Comment: @Nestor I've updated it to do a distinct lookup.  All it takes is a Distinct.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MAX(files) as max_files, id, status, dept
FROM table
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: the group by will need to have  status, dept also... but if i do that all entries will be displayed... so thats not right.. thanks tough

Comment: Why will the GROUP BY need those extra columns?

Answer (score 0):

I may be over-simplifying the problem, but:

```
select top 5 * from SLAStat order by files desc;
```